# LinkedIn Sharing content sharing in ios

Tags: ios

How do you share content in Linkedin in an iOS App?

Comment: https://github.com/pmilanez/MIS-Linkedin-Share

Comment: @krushankant I edited the question to conform to SO standards.  You don't need "Thank you's" -- just state the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ShareKit. There will probably be either native or LinkedIn-added support in iOS8, but for now, you have to use a third-party library.

http://getsharekit.com